# C# AC Power Connected / Disconnected events

Tags: c#, events

I'm writing a desktop application and would like to know if there are any events that get fired on AC power status changed.

Answer (score 2):

There is an event, which Windows sends to a window, when power setting changes. It's [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247(VS.85).aspx) and its wParam [PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372722(VS.85).aspx). If needed, you can then after receiving this event pool SystemInformation.PowerStatus as Noldorin suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's anything in the BCL that raises an event on such a change. Do you really need one anyway, given the infrequency of such status updates?

I would simply poll the [`SystemInformation.PowerStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus.aspx) property at regular intervals (i.e. some number of seconds). You can then raise an event based on this, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This is a code sample showing how to log desired changes. I've used foreign code sample. I'll link to the sample when it is mentioned.

In the main scenario we subscribe to this System Event:

```csharp
//The way we subscribe to the System Event to check when Power Mode has changed.
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;
```

This is the method we assign to the PowerModeChanged event call mentioned before:

```csharp
//The method assigned to the PowerModeChanged event call
private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //We are interested only in StatusChange cases, you may find other cases in a link below
    if (e.Mode.HasFlag(Microsoft.Win32.PowerModes.StatusChange))
    {
        //We use our custom PowerState.GetPowerLineStatus static method to define if Laptop is connected to AC
        //The return values are mentioned in a enumeration below
        //Log method is a placeholder method, you'd like to switch it to your own
        Log(PowerState.GetPowerLineStatus().ToString());
    }
}
```

You can learn more about other possible PowerModeChanges flags/fields here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.powermodes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Enumeration mentioned before:

```csharp
//Enumeration to interpret ACLineStatus in a right manner
public enum ACLineStatus : byte
{
    Offline = 0,
    Online = 1,
    Unknown = 255
}
```

This enumeration and custom `PowerState.GetPowerLineStatus()` method provided below are borrowed from here (comments were added by me):
https://www.prowaretech.com/articles/current/dot-net/power-status#!

```csharp
//A structure to access returned data properly and a method to reach pursued goal
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class PowerState
{
    //The only parameter we are interested in, so it's the only parameter interpreted
    //Make sure to keep all the other parameters with relevant types in this class, otherwise you can face bugs
    private ACLineStatus ACLineStatus;
    private byte BatteryFlag;
    private byte Reserved1;
    private int BatteryLifeTime;
    private int BatteryFullLifeTime;

    //Win32 api function import
    [DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetSystemPowerStatus")]
    private static extern bool GetSystemPowerStatusByRef(PowerState ps);

    //The method we use to get the current status of AC Power Source connection
    public static ACLineStatus GetPowerLineStatus()
    {
        PowerState ps = new PowerState();

        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) && GetSystemPowerStatusByRef(ps))
                return ps.ACLineStatus;

        return ACLineStatus.Unknown;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I search for a long time and found that this was the best way, the 'Sleep'-event was never working before

```
 private ManagementEventWatcher managementEventWatcher;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> powerValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
                         {
                             {"4", "Entering Suspend"},
                             {"7", "Resume from Suspend"},
                             {"10", "Power Status Change"},
                             {"11", "OEM Event"},
                             {"18", "Resume Automatic"}
                         };
    public void InitPowerEvents()
    {
        var q = new WqlEventQuery();
        var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");

        q.EventClassName = "Win32_PowerManagementEvent";
        managementEventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
        managementEventWatcher.EventArrived += PowerEventArrive;
        managementEventWatcher.Start();
    }
    private void PowerEventArrive(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (PropertyData pd in e.NewEvent.Properties)
        {
            if (pd == null || pd.Value == null) continue;
            var name = powerValues.ContainsKey(pd.Value.ToString())
                           ? powerValues[pd.Value.ToString()]
                           : pd.Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("PowerEvent:"+name);
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        managementEventWatcher.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to hook up to the [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.WIN32.SYSTEMEVENTS.POWERMODECHANGED%29;k%28POWERMODECHANGED%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true). 
However, you need to look at the SystemInformation.PowerStatus value to figure out what changed.